# Как не учитывать элементы листа, которые не соответствуют требованиям?

Tags: java, list

Работаю с `Date`.
Есть определенный `List data`.
В нем хранятся день рождения людей. Проблема в том, что есть дата полная (Например, "19.02.1996"), а есть без года ("25.03"), а есть вообще без возраста(null).
Я делаю метод чтобы высчитать возраст этих людей, но не могу придумать как откинуть тех людей, у которых не указан возраст.
Вот кусок кода, который сейчас у меня имеется:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    String num = data.get(i).getBdate();

    if (num != null) {
       System.out.println(num);
       String dataFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy";
       SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dataFormat);
       ...
 }
```

Хочу сделать такое условие `if(num соответствует dataFormat){ //Считать возраст}`

Comment: Дата по-английски будет date.

Comment: @КириллМалышев а по-транслиту data. Только вроде такие комменты тут не уместны. Потому, что у автора data - это данные, а дата - getBdate(). Т.е. всё прям так как Вы любите по-аглицки:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом `isValidFormat` из этого [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20232680/7485582), добавив в него обработку случая, когда вместо даты `null`.

Вот [пример](https://ideone.com/xdW45W):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy";
    String[] arr = {
        "19.02.1996",
        "25.03",
        null
    };
    for (String date: arr) {
        if (isValidFormat(dateFormat, date)) {  // Проверка даты на валидность
            System.out.println(date);
            // Делаем, что надо
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isValidFormat(String format, String value) {
    if (value == null)
        return false;
    Date date = null;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        date = sdf.parse(value);
        if (!value.equals(sdf.format(date))) {
            date = null;
        }
    } catch (ParseException ex) {}
    return date != null;
}
```

Такой способ позволит вам легко изменять формат даты, на соответствие которому нужно её проверять.

Answer (score 1):

```
list.stream()
    .filter(data->!data.getBDay().isEmpty())
    .filter(data->data.getBDay().length > 5)
    .forEach(data->{
            //Ваш код
    });
```

Comment: Только на первом же элементе, у которого getBDay() == null, возникнет исключению NullPointerException

Comment: @Sergey я не собирался давать готовое решение, а лишь натолкнул пользователя на его реализацию посредством апи 8й версии